# using a label with anonymous function

Tags: go

There's a New function inside a Pool struct in the [source code](https://github.com/gbbr/go-src/blob/master/sync/pool.go) of the `sync` package that's defined like this

```
type Pool struct {
local unsafe.Pointer // local fixed-size per-P pool, actual type is [P]poolLocal
localSize uintptr // size of the local array
// New optionally specifies a function to generate
// a value when Get would otherwise return nil.
// It may not be changed concurrently with calls to Get.
New func() interface{}
}
```

At line 103 of a [golang stack trace package](https://github.com/facebookgo/stack/blob/master/stack.go) created by Facebook, there's an anonymous function defined inside a sync pool struct like this with the `New:` label:

```
var pcsPool = sync.Pool{
    New: func() interface{} {
        return make([]uintptr, maxStackSize)
    },
}
```

So, going from the comments in the source code, I'm assuming that the Facebook package has "specified a  function to generate a value when Get would otherwise return nil," but why might it be defined with `New:` like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`New` isn't a label, it's a field name in a [`sync.Pool`](http://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Pool)

```
type Pool struct {

        // New optionally specifies a function to generate
        // a value when Get would otherwise return nil.
        // It may not be changed concurrently with calls to Get.
        New func() interface{}
        // contains filtered or unexported fields
}
```

It's no different than `N` in the following example

```
type T struct {
    N int
}

t := T{
    N: 1,
}
```